# Will a '*' (star) in globbing match only characters (i.e , a-z and 0-9)?

Tags: wildcards, csh

I havie a simple question here: does a `*` (star wildcard) match only characters (letters and numbers) in glob style? Or will it also match special characters?

In bash, `*` matches everything, while in csh `*` it matches only alphanumeric characters.

Is there any rule of compatibility for this? Can anyone clarify?

Comment: My shell is 'csh' , this could be problem ? Compatibility Issue ?

Comment: As long as you don't tell us what do you mean with 'my own scenario' and you don't give us an example it will be very difficult to help you ...

Comment: I am teaking back my statement , pls let me know the matching characters to '*' in glob styling.

Comment: Then edit your question to make it clear ...

Comment: Edited Question .

Comment: Sorry but we are still missing an example. csh `*` is matching special characters. Which characters are not matched?

Answer (score 4):

`*` is a filename pattern that matches any sequence of characters.

When used as a glob (in filename expansion/generation) `*` doesn't match slash characters (well, the pattern is checked against the list of files in the current directory) or a leading dot.

Now the definition of *character* has been changing over time. Nowaday, the definition or a character is locale dependant. Nowadays, most locales use UTF-8 encoding for text which means characters are sequences of bytes of variable length. For instance `a` is 0x61 while `é` is 0xc3 0xa9. In UTF-8, not all sequences of bytes form valid characters. For instance 0x61 0xc3 0x61 is invalid. While 0x61 translates to `a`, 0xc3 cannot translate to a character.

In most shells, `*` will also match non-characters, so `*` will expand to all the files in the current directory whose name doesn't start with `.` regardless of whether the bytes in the file names form valid characters in the current locale or not. An exception to that seems to be at least the csh-20110502 found on my Debian system (itself based on OpenBSD's csh).

```
$ touch "$(printf '\xc3')" "$(printf '\xc3\xa9')"
$ ls
?  é
$ locale charmap
UTF-8
$ bash -c 'echo *' | sed -n l
\303 \303\251$
$ csh -c 'echo *' | sed -n l
\303\251$
```

`\303` (a representation of the 0xc3 byte) is missing from the output with `csh` because that's not a valid character.

```
$ LC_ALL=C csh -c 'echo *' | sed -n l
\303 \303\251$
```

In the C locale, characters map to bytes (though the characters for values above 0x7f are not defined), so 0xc3 is one character and 0xc3 0xa9 are two characters.

Now anyway, there's no reason why you would use that `csh` on Debian. Use `tcsh` if you want a `csh`-like shell, but best is to avoid using `csh` altogether.

Answer (score 1):

From the The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 6 IEEE Std 1003.1 Section [2.13.2 Patterns Matching Multiple Characters](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_13_02)

> The asterisk ( '*' ) is a pattern that shall match any string, including the null string.

This means that `*` will match any character without restrictions.